# Receiving error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int for my array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, int, double

I'm getting this error on line 18. I don't know why the compiler wants me to cast the variable gradeNum  to type int when both the array grade and the variable gradeNum are type double. Disclaimer: This code is far from finished. The only question I have is about this error that has to do with the array grade and the variable gradeNum.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab10{

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

static String temp = "";
static double gradeNum = 0.0;
static String temp2 = "";

public static void main(String [] args) {


System.out.println("Please enter how many grades you would like to input: ");
temp = console.nextLine();
gradeNum = Double.parseDouble(temp);

double [] grade = new double [gradeNum]; 

System.out.println("Okay now please enter each individual grade: ");
temp2 = console.nextLine();


} // end of main

} // end of class Lab10
```

Answer (score 2):

what goes inside `[]`  of the `new double[size]` is the size of the double array. Not the content of the array.

Are you trying to do this?
I've assumed size as 1 here, but that you might need to adjust based on your need

```
double [] grade = new double[1]; 
grade[1] = gradeNum;
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize array and have to provide size of it that can't be double only integer. You cant create array that contains 3.6 elements only 3 or 4.

Comment: After creating array You can put double into it

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `double` to specify the array-size, according to [JLS Chapter 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html), only non-negative integer values are allowed, that is why the compiler wants you to cast the double `gradeNum` to int.

> The variables contained in an array have no names; instead they are referenced by array access expressions that **use non-negative integer** index values. These variables are called the components of the array. If an array has n components, we say n is the length of the array; the components of the array are referenced using integer indices from 0 to n - 1, inclusive.

So you need to change your code to:

```
static int gradeNum = 0;
....
gradeNum = Integer.parseInt(temp);
```